# What's the idiomatic way of describing a question by its recipient?

Tags: phrase-request

What's the idiomatic way of describing a question by its recipient?

Is "pointed on [someone]" idiomatic?

> He willingly answers his teacher's questions **that are pointed individually on
>   him**, but usually doesn't take much initiative in answering questions
>   **pointed on the whole class in general**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't "point **on** someone", although when we "point **at** someone" it means a gesture with a finger.

One "[asks](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ask)" a question, and it can be (verb)  "[directed](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/direct)" at someone.

The sentence could be

> He willingly answers his teacher's questions that are directed at him, but usually doesn't take much initiative in answering questions asked of the whole class.